# '.' is not valid at this position, Expecting : EOF, ';'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am not sure whats the problem with mysql statement. I am trying to run the below query which I took from Repository Class in eclipse from my project.

```
select distinct(al.entity) from Allocation al where al.status = 1 and  al.userDepartment.user is not null 
and al.userDepartment.department.costCode in ('finance')
and al.entity.locationFloor.id = 1 ;
```

and it shows me error on `.costCode` as well as on `.id` saying `'.' is not valid at this position, Expecting : EOF,  ';'`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Allocation table

```
Id user_department_id entity_id status
1        1              1        1
```

Entity table

```
id, entity_type_id, entity_child_type_id, location_floor_id, status
1        1                1                     1               1
```

User_Department table

```
id, user_id department_id status
1      3         4           1
```

Department table

```
id name    cost_code  status
1  finance     011      1
```

MYSQL-Workbench version is 8.0

Comment: Where do all these dots come from? `al.userDepartment.department.costCode` does not look valid to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
select distinct al.entity 
(from (Allocation al join User_Department ud on al.user_department_id = ud.department_id ) 
join Department D on d.id = al.user_department_id )
join Entity E on al.entity_id = E.id 
where al.status = 1 
and  ud.user_id is not null 
and d.name in ('finance')
and E.location_floor_id = 1 ;
```

instead of using the dots use `join` because the dots are used to get the column of a specific table that means you can only use the dots once like this `table_name.column_name`  or `table_alias.column_name`

Answer (score 0):

The code you took is not SQL, it's Java.

This is a Java property: `al.userDepartment.department.costCode`, there is no field or schema in your SQL that equals `costCode`.

The Java code seems to auto-join entities for you.

To achieve the same in SQL, you need `JOIN` like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(al.entity)
FROM Allocation al
JOIN User_Department ud
ON a.user_id = al.user_department_id
JOIN Department dep ON al.user_department_id = dep.id
-- ...
WHERE al.status = 1
```